# SCP - Transfer without any Auth (or alternative)

Tags: debian, ssh, scp

I am trying to figure out how to solve this problem:
A batch on an **unknown** pc should login in to the server and download a file. (its rbash don't be worried).

The problem is, I dont know how to get over the password authentication. The use of a public key is also not possible because I would have to copy the file to the server in the first place.

Is there an alternative with password auth? I dont want to open insecure connections to the webserver.

running Debian.

Comment: how do you login to your server currently?

Comment: Over ssh/another account
The account I want to use is restricted to only one folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just going to take a moment to appreciate the cognitive dissonance between "A batch on an **unknown** PC should log in..." and "I don't want to open insecure connections".

Okay, so.  Notwithstanding that:  You do specify in the question that it's a web server.  So on the web server put the file into a location accessible via HTTP(S).  Then, on this unknown PC, you can:

```
$ wget https://hostname.example.com/path/to/some/snazzy_file
```

or

```
$ curl -o snazzy_file --silent https://hostname.exameple.com/path/to/some/snazzy_file
```

If you don't want anyone else to get the file, you can, since it's a web server, use a set of `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` files (presuming Apache) or other means to lock down access to that file to either a range of client hosts or to a clients which provide authentication.  If you decide to use HTTP Basic Auth, the URLs used for `curl` or `wget` would then be adjusted to:  `https://username:password@host.example.com/path/to/some/snazzy_file`.

Comment: solved it thanks.